# Ruby on Rails, jwt auth, capybara cucumber testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, capybara

I have Ruby on Rails backend and one view where ReactJS frontend is mounted. Authentication by devise + jwt. I use cucumber capybara for testing frontend. How can I sign in in tests? How can I put jwt in headers in steps of test?

Feature

```
...
  Background:
   Given I am loged in user   
...
```

Steps

```
Given(/^I am loged in user$/) do
  how can I put jwt in headers here?
end
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this. You can just visit the page using something like Capybara fill in the form and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper that fill in your login form like this:

```rb
# spec/support/features_helpers.rb

def login_user(user=nil)
  visit '/#/login'

  within '#login_form' do
    fill_in 'email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'password', with: 'foobarfoo'
    page.find('button').click
  end

  expect(page).to have_no_css '#login_form'
end
```

And then use in your tests:

```rb
let(:user) { create(:user) }

before do
  login_user user
end

it '...' do
  ...
end
```